# How to show ViewController from custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I just started learning swift and don't understand how present ViewController from custom UITableViewCell when I clicked to my Collection Cell.

I have custom class MainTableViewCell.swift that has CollectionView

```
extension MainTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videos.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
    let video = videos[indexPath.item]
    cell.titleLabel.text = video.title
    cell.dateLabel.text = video.date
    cell.bgImageView.load(urlString: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/\(video.image!)/hqdefault.jpg")
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    return cell
}
```

What can I do in method didSelectItemAt?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set a delegation pattern in order to present a new view controller from a class that contains your table view. The steps are:

1. Create a `TableViewCellDelegate` protocol, and inside a table view cell class inside `didSelectItemAt` method call the protocol's method (also pass the information of collection view cell in method parameters which is required).
2. Make your table view containing view controller conform to this protocol.
3. Inside the method where you conform the `TableViewDelegate` present a new view controller.

p.s don't forget to set the `delegate` property to self in `cellForRowAt` method of table view.